# Scan for a player location and Teleport user [Bukkit]

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

I've been searching but I don't find exactly what I want...
I want to get a Player's location and if it fits with a definen location, teleport the player to another location. This is what I'm getting. No error shown in the console but nothing happens when player is in X = 300.

```
 public void onPlayerInteract(PlayerInteractEvent e)
   {
       if(e.getPlayer().getLocation().getX()==300)
       {
           e.getPlayer().teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getServer().getWorld("world"), 310, 75, 300));
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are three mistakes in this and to get them working correctly I fixed my code:

```
public void onPlayerMove(PlayerMoveEvent e)
{ // On player movement!
    if((int) e.getPlayer().getLocation().getX() == 300)
    // If you cast as int 3.9 or 3.01 it will return 3
    {
        e.getPlayer().teleport(new Location(Bukkit.getWorld("world"), 310, 75, 300));
        /* There is a bug in bukkit plugins since 1.6.4.
         * You need to get the world just by getWorld(); not
         *  getServer().getWorld();
         */
    }
}
```

This is working at 10/10 :)

Answer (score 0):

X is a floating point number, and it's never *exactly* 300. Try

```
if(Math.abs(e.getPlayer().getLocation().getX()-300) < 1){
```

Comment: I got your idea, but I put it like: `if((int)(e.getPlayer().getLocation().getX())==300)` and now is working! But now it shows an error in console: could not pass PlayerInteractEvent. Any idea of this?

Comment: @user3718577 No idea. It's out of the scope of this question, though. [Perhaps google it?](https://www.google.com/search?q=could+not+pass+PlayerInteractEvent)

Comment: I got it. Says null pointer in location lol. Anyways, thanks, you gave me an idea of what I had to do :D

Answer (score 0):

You're checking if the player's x coordinate is equal to exactly 300, which is probably never the case. It's most like a decimal number like so `300.05456`.

What you probably wanted to do, was to check if the player's is standing on a block with `x = 300`. If so, this is what you should do instead.

```
if (e.getPlayer().getLocation().getBlockX() == 300) {
    // Do stuff
}
```

Comment: Note that the result from `getX()` is cast to `int` before being compared to 300.  (Casts have higher precedence than the `==` operator.)